# How to get a list of android installed apps which accept http: as URI?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

i guess packagemanager is the starting point but it seems that it is quite complicated.
i want to list the set of supporting app accepting http: in a list with its launcher icon, clicking it will launch the app.
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "accepts http"?  Do you mean they're browsers?  If so you don't mean accept http, you mean it can VIEW html.  Do you mean that has an http:// local url?  Something else completely?

Comment: not necessarily, maybe some apps may just do some url bookmarking, many possibilities. Browser should be a subset.  thanks

Comment: Well since you can't even define what you mean by "accept http", then we can't answer this question.  But its probably impossible, since you seem to have a very wide ranging definition of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example will show how to get a list of application that can open HTTP URLs.

```
   String url = "http://www.example.com"; // you can give any url here
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager()
    .queryIntentActivities(i, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
     //you will get all information you need from `resolveInfo`
     //eg:for package name - resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
    }
```

Comment: thank you. i will have a try, how about if i want to do it more generic, e.g. i want to list uri with mail:    i don't want to hardcode some url or mail addresses thanks?